# How to know the file path in which the jinja environment is loading the file from?

Tags: python, jinja2

This is my jinja loader:

```
template_dir = '/static/templates/'
jinja_env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('package-name', 'static/templates/'))
```

No matter where I put my static/templates directory, I get this as an error:

```
  raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: test.html
```

So, I want to know where is my jinja_env searching the template from? Is there a way in which I can get a file path after I set the environment?